# C# DataGridView cell errortext detection before row is drawn

Tags: c#, winforms, validation, datagridview

I have a datagridview in which i paste rows copied from an excel file.
When my rows are populated i validate each cell on the CellFormattingEvent.

```
switch (e.ColumnIndex)
{
  case 10:
  if (dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex] == null || dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString().Trim() == "")
  {
  dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex - 1].ErrorText = "Product code not found!";
  }
  break;
}
```

My purpose here is to hide all rows except the ones which contain an error on a button press.
Now my problem is that I cant set the ErrorText of rows I cant physically see in the datagrid.

My question is: Is there a way to validate the cells I can not see besides programatically scrolling the datagrid as I add them?

Comment: Bound or unbound mode?

Comment: Databound to a list of objects, had previously a problem which prevented me from doing the easiest thing to solve this, which was to validate on the RowsAdded event. Fixed this issue and now it works fine with validating on the RowsAdded.

Comment: Good, but much better is to implement `IDataErrorInfo` in your object and forget about concrete control events. It works for any profession grid component, as well as with single item data binding.